# Amalgamated free products and Stallings' theorem on ends of groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G=A\ast_C B$ be a non-trivial free product with amalgamation. Then, if $C$ has index greater than two in $A$ or $B$, $G$ has infinitely many ends if it is infinite and the amalgamating subgroup is finite, by Stallings' Theorem on Ends of Groups. My question is,

> What does it mean for the amalgamating subgroup to be finite?

Do you have to take two finite subgroups of $A$ and $B$, say $H$ and $K$ respectively, and amalgamate them (i.e. they are finite *before* the amalgamation), or can $H$ and $K$ be infinite but they map to a finite subgroup of $G$ (so they are finite *after* the amalgamation). For example,

$G=F_2 \ast_{C_n} C_n=\langle a, b, c; b=c, c^n\rangle$

and here $H=\langle b\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}$ with $K=\langle c\rangle\cong C_n$. (I'm pretty sure this is a free product with amalgamation - but I'm never quite sure about this stuff...)

Comment: You are misquoting Stallings's theorem.  Consider the infinite dihedral group.  You need $C$ to have index at least $3$ in one of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: I don't want to be "that guy", but you still do not understand Stallings's theorem.  The group $C_4\ast_{C_2} C_4$ fits your question, but is one-ended.

Comment: @SteveD: What, you don't want to be helpful!? You are right, I do not understand Stallings' theorem. As I said in the comments to the answer, below, I prefer to ignore this stuff and just pretend it doesn't exist...

Comment: @SteveD:  I have to admit I didn't even read the bit about Stallings' Theorem, since my attention was drawn immediately to the fact that user1729 didn't understand amalgamated products, and so I just concentrated on that.  The question itself could have been asked without any reference to Stallings' Theorem.

Comment: @TaraB: Yes, but my motivation was to try and understand Stallings' theorem. I just got bogged down on the way...

Comment: @Steve: $C_4*_{C_2}C_4$ is 2-ended.

Comment: @YvesCornulier: Yes that seems to be a typo on my part.  I don't remember exactly what the question was like when I left that response, but I believe I was more focused on finding groups of that type that had finitely many ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amalgamation only identifies two isomorphic subgroups, it doesn't perform any further quotienting.  So the group you are amalgamating over has to be isomorphic to a subgroup of both $A$ and $B$.  Thus your first statement is correct.

You cannot form an amalgamated free product of $F_2$ and a finite group with non-trivial amalgamation, because $F_2$ has no non-trivial finite subgroups.

Comment: Ah, okay. One day I will understand these things...

Comment: Are you still not quite clear on the definition of the amalgamated product?  I can add some more detail if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: No, I just keep on forgetting the definition. I had a picture in my head, but the arrows went the wrong way...

Comment: Oh, I see.  Okay.  Are you familiar with Bass-Serre theory?  If so, it helps to keep in mind the picture of an amalgamated product as the fundamental group of a graph of groups consisting of a single edge (the vertex groups are $A$ and $B$ and the edge group is $C$).

Comment: I am familiar with Bass-Serre theory, and I know the picture you are talking about...but...I've never really found it useful, and so I tend to just ignore amalgamated free products and pretend they don't exist. I should probably have another crack at "Trees", and actually do some examples this time...

Comment: Doing some exercises about free products with amalgamation would probably be very helpful in understanding them.  I think there are some good ones in one of the books called "Combinatorial Group Theory", but I can't remember whether it was Magnus-Karrass-Solitar or Lyndon and Schupp.